# Cómo determinar si un string contiene caracteres alfanuméricos y signos como '-' ó '_'

Tags: javascript, function

tengo el siguiente inconveniente, necesito identificar si un objeto que recibo de una BD contiene caracteres alfanuméricos y signos como "-" ó "_" o estos los puedo omitir. Estoy intentando lo siguiente:

```
function DatoAlfaNum(){
  let prueba = 'SM-6014567823'; // Este es el value que recibo desde la BD
  let char_alpha = /^[\w\D-]+$/;
  
  if(prueba == char_alpha){
    return 'Es una cadena alfanumerica'
  }
  else {
    return 'No es una cadena alfanumerica'
  }}
```

Pero no me me funciona, agradecería su ayuda, mil gracias

Comment: ¿Quieres saber si la cadena sin "_" y "-" tiene alfanumericos?

Comment: Hola, si la cadena es alfanumérica, si contiene letras y números, se puede omitir esos signos

Answer (score 1):

Necesitas ejecutar la expression regular con `exec` asi:

```js
function DatoAlfaNum(){
  let prueba = 'SM-6014567823'; // Este es el value que recibo desde la BD
  let char_alpha = /^[\w\D-]+$/;
  
  if(char_alpha.exec(prueba)){
    return 'Es una cadena alfanumerica'
  }
  else {
    return 'No es una cadena alfanumerica'
  }}
  
  console.log(DatoAlfaNum())
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu apoyo, pero si a let prueba, le quito las letras 'SM-', me sigue diciendo: 'Es una cadena alfanumerica' =/

Comment: Edito, ya lo solucioné de la siguiente forma jeje

`function DatoAlfaNum(){ 
  let prueba = 'SM-601670894';
  let digitos = /\d/;
  let letras = /[A-Za]/;
  
  if(digitos.exec(prueba) && letras.exec(prueba)){
    return true
}else {
  return false
}}`

Answer (score 1):

Para comparar la cadena de texto con las expresiones regulares tendrías que utilizar el método `test`, esta condición `if` te retornará `true` si la cadena cumple con la expresión regular:

```js
function DatoAlfaNum(){ 
  let prueba = 'SM-6014567823';
  char_alpha = /^[\w\D-]+$/;

  if(char_alpha.test(prueba)){
    return 'Es una cadena alfanumerica'
  } else {
    return 'No es una cadena alfanumerica'
  } 
}

console.log(DatoAlfaNum())
```

Comment: Hola, gracias por tu apoyo, pero si a let prueba, le quito las letras 'SM-', me sigue diciendo: 'Es una cadena alfanumerica' =/

Comment: Lo solucioné de la siguiente forma 
`function DatoAlfaNum(){ 
  let prueba = 'SM-601670894';
  let digitos = /\d/;
  let letras = /[A-Za]/;
  
  if(digitos.exec(prueba) && letras.exec(prueba)){
    return true
}else {
  return false
}}`

Comment: Era problema de la expresión regular, que bueno que lo haya solucionado, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Anoto la solución por si alguno más adelante necesita algo parecido, lo solucioné así:

```
function DatoAlfaNum(){ 
  let prueba = 'SM-601670894';
  let digitos = /\d/;
  let letras = /[A-Za-z]/;
  
  if(digitos.exec(prueba) && letras.exec(prueba)){
    return true
}else {
  return false
}}
```

De esta forma evaluará si la cadena es alfanumérica

Comment: No olvides aceptar tu respuesta cuando transcurra el tiempo mínimo.